# How can I use res.body.Close in "for" loop as I need to make multiple calls to the same API?

Tags: go

I want to use *res.body.Close* in a *for* loop, but before being able to close the TCP connection it is being recalled. What is the optimal way to use it?

This is my code snippet for reference:

```
// Function call
serviceList := RecursiveResourceMapApiCall(resourceItem)
.
.
.
func RecursiveResourceMapApiCall(resourceItem types.ResourceItem) (serviceList []types.Services) {
    fmt.Println("RecursiveResourceMapApiCall")
    // var err error
    if len(resourceItem.ServiceRefs) == 0 {
        fmt.Println("service at this point: ", resourceItem.ID)
        serviceDetail := types.Services {
            Name:    resourceItem.ID,
            Version: resourceItem.Version,
        }
        serviceList = append(serviceList, serviceDetail)
        // Should I close the response body here? I have
        // to change the return type of function then
        return serviceList
    }
    var resourceMapResponse types.ResourceMapResponse
    for i := 0; i < len(resourceItem.ServiceRefs); i++ {
        // FetchDetailsFromResourceMapService is the API call
        response, err := allocatorStore.FetchDetailsFromResourceMapService(resourceItem.ServiceRefs[i])
        if err == nil && response.StatusCode == 200 {
            data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
            err := json.Unmarshal(data, &resourceMapResponse)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("error in unmarshalling resource map response", err)
            }
            fmt.Println("Length of data in response: ", len(resourceMapResponse.Data.Resources), "Resource Data received: ", resourceMapResponse.Data.Resources)
            if resourceMapResponse.StatusCode == 0 {
                // Making recursive call here as there
                // is data to process still
                serviceList = RecursiveResourceMapApiCall(resourceMapResponse.Data.Resources[0])
            } else if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Error on resource request", err.Error())
            } else {
                fmt.Println("Error on resource request", response.StatusCode, response.Body)
            }
            response.Body.Close()
        }
    }
    return serviceList
}
```

I know that *response.body.Close* stops resource leak by closing TCP layer connection. But I am not able to close it as it is being called recursively. I thought of putting it in base condition. But it doesn't feel right. What’s the best practise here?

Also, can there be any repercussions if I use res.body.Close() in loop?

Comment: You can just close the body after you're done reading it (after the line `data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(repsonse.Body)`). You'll also have to adjust the print line later. That way you close the body before making the recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

You can close right after the read:

```
package main

import (
   "net/http"
   "os"
   "time"
)

func main() {
   for i := 0; i < 9; i++ {
      res, err := http.Get("https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/webpack-chunks/8374.en.js")
      if err != nil {
         panic(err)
      }
      os.Stdout.ReadFrom(res.Body)
      if err := res.Body.Close(); err != nil {
         panic(err)
      }
      time.Sleep(time.Second)
   }
}
```

or you can move it to its own function:

```
package main

import (
   "net/http"
   "os"
   "time"
)

func get() error {
   res, err := http.Get("https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/webpack-chunks/8374.en.js")
   if err != nil {
      return err
   }
   defer res.Body.Close()
   if _, err := os.Stdout.ReadFrom(res.Body); err != nil {
      return err
   }
   return nil
}

func main() {
   for i := 0; i < 9; i++ {
      err := get()
      if err != nil {
         panic(err)
      }
      time.Sleep(time.Second)
   }
}
```